# Left adjoint to forgetful functor from groups to groupoids, generalizing injective inclusions to free product of groups

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, adjoint-functors, groupoids, free-product

Is there a left adjoint $F$ to the "forgetful" inclusion functor $U$ from the category of groups (interpreted as groupoids with one object $*$) to the category of groupoids? If so, then letting $\eta$ be the unit of the adjunction, is $\eta_G : G \to UF(G)$ faithful for every groupoid $G$?

I suspect this question is related to the construction of free products of groups, and in the case that a groupoid is a disjoint union of groups, then $F$ specializes to the free product of the groups (indeed, if a left adjoint exists then it preserves coproducts). My intuition says we could take words on all the morphisms regardless of composability, and then allow composable morphisms to reduce when they are adjacent in a word. If this intuition is correct, the question I am most interested in is whether this "free group on a groupoid $G$" has an injective inclusion from each $G(x, y)$, analogous to how the free product of groups has injective inclusions from each factor.

What about the corresponding situation with categories of monoids and categories?

Comment: The inclusion from each $G(x,y)$ that you ask for is exactly what the unit of the adjunction does.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a genuine adjunction but there is a sort of weaker unnatural adjunction, I believe, essentially of the form: break a groupoid into its connected components, take an arbitrary automorphism group at a point in each component (these are well-determined up to **unnatural** isomorphism; any connected groupoid is equivalent, but not isomorphic, as a category to its full subcategory at a point) and take the free products of these groups. I am not sure what the formal properties of this construction are; I don't believe its a true adjoint

Comment: @EricWofsey I agree if the adjunction exists and if the components are inclusions, but I wonder how that could be shown. If this were just the coproduct of groups, then we would know the coprojections are injections because they are split monics. But the general situation here doesn't seem to be the limit of some similar diagram. A group-theoretic approach to showing that the coprojections are injections is to use van der Waerden's trick to prove uniqueness of normal forms, but I don't know how well that can be generalized to the groupoid setting.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize you meant the word "inclusion" to imply injectivity.

Comment: Ah, fair - I will edit the question to explicitly state this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us first suppose $G$ is a connected groupoid; fix an object $x$ of $G$.  For each other object $y$ of $G$, also fix an isomorphism $f_y:x\to y$.  If $H$ is a group, then a functor $G\to H$ is uniquely determined by a homomorphism $\operatorname{Aut}(x)\to H$ together with a choice of element of $H$ to map each $f_y$ to.  It follows that the left adjoint $F(G)$ evaluated on $G$ can be described as the free product of $\operatorname{Aut}(x)$ with a free group on the set of objects of $G$ other than $x$.

For a general groupoid $G$, then, $F(G)$ is the free product of the groups given by each of its connected components in this way.  In particular, then, since the inclusions of groups into a free product of groups are injective, the unit of the adjunction $\eta_G:G\to UF(G)$ is faithful.

Here is an alternative description of the left adjoint that also works just as well for the forgetful functor from monoids to categories.  An element of $F(G)$ is a finite sequence of non-identity morphisms of $G$ such that no two consecutive morphisms in the sequence are composable (call such sequences *reduced*).  Composition of two such finite sequences is defined by concatenation, and then turning it into a reduced sequence by repeatedly composing any adjacent composable morphisms in the sequence and removing any identity morphisms.  (Some work is then needed to check that this is associative; this is very similar to checking associativity of the multiplication in the free product of groups constructed using words.)  This description makes it even easier to see that the unit of the adjunction is faithful (and also that it is faithful in the case of categories and monoids).

By the way, if you just want *existence* of the left adjoints, that is easy by abstract nonsense.  For instance, it follows from the adjoint functor theorem, since groups are closed under limits in the category of groupoids (or monoids are closed under limits in the category of categories).  Or concretely, you can just take the set of strings representing formal compositions of morphisms of your groupoid (or category) and say that two strings are equivalent if they become equal under every functor to a group (or monoid).  A description like this isn't very useful for figuring out whether the unit is faithful, though, unless you can get a better handle on that equivalence relation.